How to use plotnine in Spyder IPython console and Plots tab
I'm using the Spyder IDE and plotnine to create ggplot objects.  I am able to successfully create the ggplot objects and store them in a variable (i.e. gg).  When I try to use the gg variable in the console window to have the plot appear in the Plots tab by issuing the following command:
filename = 'data.xlsx'
data = get_data(filename)  # function that loads data from an exce file
gg = (
        ggplot(data, aes(x=data.index, y="Weight"))
        + geom_point()
        + geom_smooth(span=0.2)
        + labs(title="Weight Trend", y="Pounds")
     )
gg.show()

as soon as I type the following:
gg.show(

as best as I can tell, the Spyder environment automatically makes a repr(gg) call.  The plot appears in the Plots tab and it triggers the following plotnine warnings:
C:\Users\Daddy\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\oinspect.py:1014: FutureWarning: Using repr(plot) to draw and show the plot figure is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use plot.show().
C:\Users\Daddy\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\plotnine\stats\smoothers.py:347: PlotnineWarning: Confidence intervals are not yet implemented for lowess smoothings.

Completing the command with a closing parenthesis and pressing  adds another plot to the Plots tab and issues another lowess smoothings warning, but not the repr() warning.
Questions:

How do I suppress the automatic triggering of the repr() command as I'm typing gg.show(?
How do I suppress the warning messages, or at least only have them appear the first time and not every time?

Version Info:

  - plotnine:  plotnine-0.13.6
  - Spyder:  5.5.5
  - Python:  3.11.9 64-bit
  - IPython 8.22.2
  - Qt5:  5.15.2
  - PyQt5:  5.15.10

